# IBM CDC for zOS VSAM - how do I change parameters with the SET CONFIG command?

Tags: ibm-data-replication

I would like to change some of the source file parameters. As per the manual, it says we can modify using SET CONFIG parameters?

Is this command to be issued in the console ? Or how does it make sure this command belongs to CDCSRVR while we issue this in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

You can issue the console command to set the configuration as below:

```
“F  CDCSRVR,SET,CONFIG, ...”
```

For example:

```
/F CDCSRVR,SET,CONFIG,SERVICE=LOG,LOGBUFSIZE=‘1024000’
```